# AVMutableVideoComposition doesn't play back

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation

my setup is the following:
In this segment of my app a user can put videos in a row.
Those videos may have a gap between them or start at a later time as 0.

To achieve this I added a function that adds a all black video and loop it during every gap:

```
func getBlackVideoSegments(timerange: CMTimeRange) -> [AVCompositionTrackSegment] {
    var compositionTrackSegments = [AVCompositionTrackSegment]()
    if CMTimeCompare(timerange.duration, RTGlobals.blackVideo.duration) == -1 {
        let compositionTrackSegment = AVCompositionTrackSegment(URL: RTGlobals.blackVideoURL, trackID: RTGlobals.blackVideoAssetTrack.trackID, sourceTimeRange: CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, timerange.duration), targetTimeRange: timerange)
        compositionTrackSegments.append(compositionTrackSegment)
        addVideoCompositionInstruction(RTGlobals.blackVideoAssetTrack, timeRange: timerange, assetTrack: videoCompositionTrack)
    } else {
        var currentStart = timerange.start
        var filledDuration = kCMTimeZero
        while CMTimeCompare(filledDuration, timerange.duration) == -1 {
            let durationToFill = CMTimeSubtract(timerange.duration, filledDuration)
            var durationAdded = RTGlobals.blackVideo.duration
            if CMTimeCompare(durationAdded, durationToFill) == 1 {
                durationAdded = durationToFill
            }

            let compositionTrackSegment = AVCompositionTrackSegment(URL: RTGlobals.blackVideoURL, trackID: RTGlobals.blackVideoAssetTrack.trackID, sourceTimeRange: CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, durationAdded), targetTimeRange: CMTimeRangeMake(currentStart, durationAdded))
            compositionTrackSegments.append(compositionTrackSegment)
            addVideoCompositionInstruction(RTGlobals.blackVideoAssetTrack, timeRange: CMTimeRangeMake(currentStart, durationAdded), assetTrack: videoCompositionTrack)

            currentStart = CMTimeAdd(currentStart, durationAdded)
            filledDuration = CMTimeAdd(filledDuration, durationAdded)
        }
    }
    return compositionTrackSegments
}
```

And here is how I set the instructions:

```
func addVideoCompositionInstruction(videoAssetTrack: AVAssetTrack, timeRange: CMTimeRange, assetTrack: AVAssetTrack) {
    let instruction = AVMutableVideoCompositionInstruction()
    instruction.timeRange = timeRange
    let layerInstruction = AVMutableVideoCompositionLayerInstruction(assetTrack: assetTrack)

    let videoSize = CGSizeMake(1920.0, 1080.0)

    var transform = videoAssetTrack.preferredTransform
    var scale:CGFloat = 1.0
    var offset:CGFloat = 0.0

    if fabs(videoAssetTrack.preferredTransform.b) == 1.0 && fabs(videoAssetTrack.preferredTransform.c) == 1.0 {
        scale = videoSize.height / videoAssetTrack.naturalSize.width
        offset = (videoSize.width - (videoAssetTrack.naturalSize.height * scale)) / 2.0
    } else {
        scale = videoSize.height / videoAssetTrack.naturalSize.height
    }
    transform = CGAffineTransformConcat(CGAffineTransformConcat(transform, CGAffineTransformMakeScale(scale, scale)), CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(offset, 0))

    layerInstruction.setTransform(transform, atTime: timeRange.start)

    instruction.layerInstructions = [layerInstruction]

    instructions.append(instruction)
}
```

The instructions and the segments are all seamless and fill the whole composition at the end.

However, every time I have those black video segments added, playback fails. The player just plain stops at the time, where the black videos come.

Does anybody see the problem? I just can't get my head around it.

Thanks a lot!

Andreas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the answer to my question is quite simple: just update to iOS 9.3
Apple obviously has a broken framework at the moment.
There are still cases, where it doesn't work perfectly, but it's fine.
I guess it's going to be fixed in 9.4

Bye!
Andreas